# Abstracted LCD Density

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

How do you calculate the Abstracted LCD Density for an AVD ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Abstracted LCD Density is measured in dots per inch (see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)).

The [wikipedia article on Pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density) has a helpful section explaining how to calculate this: basically the number of pixels per inch along the diagonal can be calculated by this formula, where `x` and `y` are the horizontal and vertical resolution (so that `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is the length of the diagonal in pixels), and `d` is the length of the diagonal in inches:

```
sqrt(x*x + y*y)/d
```

So for example, a [LG Optimus One P500](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_one_p500-3516.php) is listed as having a screen resolution of `320` by `480`, and a diagonal screen size of `3.2` inches, so it would have a density very close to `180dpi`.

Comment: the `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` is the formula to calculate a diagonal distance of a rectangle. So this equation calculates the length of the diagonal in pixels and then divides that number by inches. Hence, pixels/inch units (DPI).

Comment: Thanks, included that for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know whats Abstracted Density really means but can this help ?

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics=new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
float density=displayMetrics.density;
```