# How to make an emulator for specific device resolution(HTC Cha-Cha)?

Tags: android, android-emulator

**EDIT**

Everyone can try to make an emulator for this phone http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_chacha-3787.php to see what I mean. The icons will be huge and the screen you get is not the same as on the real phone.

Here are the specs:
*Display: TFT capacitive touchscreen, 256K colors

Size: 480 x 320 pixels, 2.6 inches (~222 ppi pixel density)*

---

I tried to make an emulator for a specific Android phone, but the resolution was all wrong. So I will write what I did, and I hope someone will correct me.

First I go to *GSMArena.com* and pick some phone (I'll use a random here)

**Sony Ericsson Xperia PLAY**
[image]

I see that the size of the screen is 480x854 with a density of 245 ppi.

Then I create a new emulator machine with WVGA854 (LARGE type of screen) and I manually set the DPI to 245 (HDPI).

Is this correct: 245ppi == 245dpi?

Sometimes this works, but most times, I get big icons on a small screen, especially when I try to make an emulator for NORMAL screen phones which have resolution of around 240ppi. When I compare such screen on the emulator with the original phone screen snapshots, I see it's just not the same.

So what is the best way, to create an emulator, for a specific mobile phone, so that it **exactly match** the manufacturer's **screen size and pixel density**?

Comment: I have no answer but if it makes you feel any better i work with a 120 dpi device in the emulator, and once in every few reboots android decides to ignore my lcd density setting as well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Eclipse

```
Window - Android SDK and AVD Manager - New
```

in `Skin`  select `Resolution` and give 480 X 854

and in `Hardware` click on `New` select "Abstract LCD Density" and change it's value to Density you get from below formula (if its given in `ppi` in the device specification) or keep it as it is if given in LCD density.

and then start that AVD.

**EDIT**

Yes you are right and I search a bit more and found Formula to Convert PPI to Abstact LCD Density here in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533300/abstracted-lcd-density)**.

> sqrt(x*x + y*y)/d

where x and y are the horizontal and vertical resolution (so that sqrt(x*x + y*y) is the length of the diagonal in pixels), and d is the length of the diagonal in inches.

Hope this ends your search now.

Comment: Try this phone http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_chacha-3787.php and you'll see what I mean. The UI does not look like on the real phone.

Comment: Hey, again I get ~245px?????? Try this formula for ChaCha and see it yourself. Any ideas now?