# How do I know how much DPI the device has?

Tags: android, screen, resolution

How do I know how much DPIs a device has (and thus if it's ldpi / mdpi / hdpi / xhdpi, - and screen size, which is also measured in dp - xlarge / large / normal / small -  according to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)?

I know the device's resolution and diagonal size, for example:

> Display   TFT LCD, 3.5 in (89 mm) diagonal.
>
> 320×480 px HVGA with Gorilla Glass
>
> 16M colors

(Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace)

Don't need it programmatically, just to calculate myself.

Comment: I think the edit of this answer can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749212/how-to-make-an-emulator-for-specific-device-resolutionhtc-cha-cha/9749278#9749278

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [DPI calculator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html) to calculate dpis, and Figure 1 in the [dev docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to determine whether its ldpi, mdpi, etc.

Comment: The result is 164.83 PPI, is that 164.83 dip?

Comment: DPI aka PPI is the density of the screen. dip is a unit for specifying size of UI stuff in a screen-density independent way. If you mean to ask if PPI value you got is the DPi value, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I think DPI reffers to printers... IN your case DPI = PPI. Please correct me if i'm wrong [edit: I'm wrong :P]

'So a 1200 dpi printer uses 1200 dots of ink in every inch to make up the colours. If you were printing a 300 PPI image, then every pixel would be made up of 16 smaller ink dots (1200 DPI x 1200 DPI / 300 PPI x 300 PPI). A lower DPI would have fewer ink dots making up each pixel, which would make the colour look worse. A higher DPI would have more ink dots for each pixel and should give more accurate colour (especially under close examination).'

Comment: But why in the Android's developer's site everything is described in dpi - ldpi, mdpi, etc.? The unit used in code is dp but in the documentation they talk about dpi, is that different?

Comment: Oh, in that context, this should provide you with a more thorough answer

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/what-is-the-difference-between-dpi-dots-per-inch-and-ppi-pixels-per-inch