# Which emulator should I use for a Huawei Y300 and Y530?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to emulate a Huawei Y530. According to [this site](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_ascend_y530-6103.php), it has the following specifications:

Screen: 480 x 854 pixels, 4.5 inches (~218 ppi pixel density)

This is what my WEB APP looks like on the actual device:

[image]

And this is what it looks like on a emulator, with the following specification:

Target: Android 4.3 - API Level 18 
Device: 4" WVGA (Nexus S) (480x800 hdpi)

[image]

I know there is a difference in the height of the two devices, but still I believe that the emulator should show something similar to what the actual device is showing.

I tried to find the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` of the real device with the following code:

```
var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }
alert (viewportwidth);
alert(viewportheight);
```

The result is width: 320px and height: 544px

The `innerWidth` on the emualtor is: 480px and the `innerHeight`: 756px

Since the real device had a width of 320px, i tried using an emulator with the following specs:

Screen: 3.2" QVGA (ADP2) (320 x 480 mdpi)

With the following result:

[image]

Comment: I found something similar in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749212/how-to-make-an-emulator-for-specific-device-resolutionhtc-cha-cha 

But there is no "Resolution" option

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new emulator if the app will be developed only for this particular phone. The image attached emulates the exact properties of the Huawei Ascend Y530 phone.

[image: New Emulator Screen]

Alternatively, if the app is being developed for different phone having different screen sizes, I would take a look at the xml file for the layout. Take note of the following attributes, like placing form widgets in relation to other widgets. For example: `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ukFlag"` for the Danish flag. There are actually several layout parameters you can paly around with until you get the right layout:

- Layout_toLeftOf
- Layout_toRightOf
- Layout_above
- Layout_below

You can also setup the positioning of the widget, to be either left_based, right_based or centred.

Hope this would help you better: [Android Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. This is a web app, developed with Cordova, so I am not sure that Android Layouts will work. However, I will try to use the image and see what happens

Comment: Personally I always used Eclipse to develop apps, but I guess Cordova uses some sort of xml layout as this is default for Android.

Comment: Cordova is a platform for building native mobile applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I downloaded Android 1.5 through the SDK manager, but it doesnt show up under Target. Also, I can only choose armeabi-v7a as the CPU. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Android 1.5 is outdated. I would recommend you download a later version (2.3 or later is suggested as most Android mobile phones work on these OSs'). Using armeabi-v7a as the CPU is great.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing too much in how you have done your application, it seems you are using fixed units like pixels to specify size. As this project is a web app, maybe you should consider to use what is called a `Responsive Design` approach. In that way your content can adjust to whatever size the screen is.

I'll let you a couple of useful articles to learn more about this:

- [Responsive Web Design in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)
- [Responsive Design Presentation](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/)
- [Responsive Design Examples](http://designmodo.com/responsive-design-examples/)

Comment: I already use media queries. For instance, @media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-height: 900px)- but as you can see on the screenshots, there is a huge difference in what the real device displays compared to what the emulator displays

Comment: Mmm, so I believe it's not about the emulator itself. What version of Android the Huawei Y530 has?