# Android - Eclipse emulators for all phones?

Tags: android

Hi I want to create multiple emulators to test my applications, but i am not sure for the settings for each emulator, I know the resolutions of common phones, but i am not sure for other settings such as DPI.

I believe "Abstract LCD density" option is for DPI in emulator ?

Emulator1 (For example samsung galaxy ace)
Res: 320x480
Abstract LCD density (DPI): ?

Emulator2 (For example Htc desire S)
Res: 480x800
Abstract LCD density (DPI): ?

Emulator3 (For example galaxy nexus)
Res: 640x960
Abstract LCD density (DPI): ?

Emulator4 (For example Samsung galaxy S III)
Res: 720x1280
Abstract LCD density (DPI): ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533300/abstracted-lcd-density

Answer (score 0):

I know one:

Emulator1 (For example samsung galaxy ace) Res: 320x480 Abstract LCD density (DPI): 165

Answer (score 0):

please refer the following link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density