# Formatting issue regarding the Galaxy S and Galaxy S2

Tags: android, android-layout, formatting, emulation, galaxy

I've run into a formatting issue regarding the **Galaxy S** and **Galaxy S2**.  Perhaps someone can share some insight.  When testing my app on the two emulators which I downloaded from the Samsung site, the emulator pulls graphic resources from the `drawable-xhdpi` folder and the graphics are way too large.  I confirmed this by setting different graphics in each `drawable-<density>` folder.  The phone specs for the **S2** are `480 x 800 pixels`, `4.3"` screen size (*works out to ~217ppi screen density*) so I would expect the emulator to pull from the `hpdi folder`.   The emulator setting for the the S2 declares an abstracted LCD density of `300` while `hw.lcd.width and hw.lcd.height` are `480 and 800` respectively.  Is the abstracted LCD Density set incorrectly by the manufacturer and should I change it in the hardware settings to `217` to get an accurate representation on the actual device?  I haven't been able to test on a Galaxy S or S2 device and I'd hate to have to write a special case to deal with a particular phone type as this is bad practice.

Comment: Question 1:  Why are graphics pulled from the xhpdi folder?
Question 2:  Are the settings in the emulator incorrect?

Comment: @user1608385 try to change the _pixel density_ property of your AVD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533300/abstracted-lcd-density .

Comment: The pixel density options are in a drop-down list.  217 is not an option.  Shouldn't I get the same result by changing the value in config-ini and hardware-quemu.ini inside the avd folder for the Galaxy S2 emulator?